# Why inside form button size and outside form button size is different after same style?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

Style is same but inside form button size and outside form button size is not same. Outside form button text-content apply extra padding around it. Same issue with  a tag. Why this is happening? How to solve it? Also for button user agent stylesheet override my font. How to fix it?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1.5px solid #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn--orange {
  color: #e99d0f;
  border: 1px solid #e99d0f;
}

.btn--red {
  color: #ff2727;
  border: 1px solid #ff2727;
}

.section-info {
  width: 60%;
}

.section-info img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.section-info__nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.section-info a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container section-info">
  <div class="section-info__nav">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn--orange">Edit</a>
    <button class="btn btn--red">Delete</button>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
      <button class="btn btn--red">Delete</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first look, it could be a bit confusing but if you look at the style inheritance with more attention you will find out a little difference between them.

### Lets get into it step by step

As we can see there is `display: flex;` attribute within the provided style.

```css
.section-info__nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

As we know flex will only affect the direct children of a `div`, so here what we got:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn--orange">Edit</a>
<button class="btn btn--red">Delete</button>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  ...
</form>
```

There are three direct children to the provided `div` (`a`, `button`, `form`). The other button within the `form` won't take effect of the `flex` display since the form itself got display `block` by default.

### Why this is happening at all?

As we know **`flex` display in the default situation will stretch the content to match the exact `height`** (There is `44px` available in `section-info__nav`, so each button height with display `flex` will be `44px`). But when we got a **display `block`**, all items with this kind of **display will put in the document just by their normal form and size**, so since the button class is:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

the sum of the `padding`, `border`, and `font-size` will be `34px` (`10px` lower than actually available height in the `div`). So the `button` will add at the beginning of div and in comparison with other buttons, it will look likes a dumb.

**NOTE:** In order to **prevent items from fitting the entire available space** in your `div` you can **control them by `align-items`** attribute. But in your particular case, **since `<a>` don't have a default `line-height`** attribute you should add specific `line-height` attribute to your `.btn` class in order to align all of your items properly.

### How to fix this?

Simply add flex display to your form like this:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: How to prevent flex from stretch the content to match the height?

Comment: @MdMredulJaman You can simply control it with `align-items` attribute in flexboxes with row direction. But since `<a>` tag itself don't have an actual `line-height` it won't follow the `align-items` properly and you should add a specific `line-height` to your `.btn` class in order to make all your items aligned properly.

Answer (score 1):

because your form is not flex.you should just add cod below in your form css:

```
display: flex;
```